# get applicationContext in TextView.setText()

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview, subclass

I'm building a `TextView` subclass to change the text that is inserted in the `android:text`. For instance, I want to capitalize the whole text but, to make sure that it is needed, I need to access the Application instance (I have a boolean that tells if it must or not be capitalized).

I implemented this subclass:

```
public class UpperTextView extends TextView {

private Context context;

public UpperTextView(Context context) {
    super(context);
    this.context = context;
}

public UpperTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) {
    super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    this.context = context;
}

public UpperTextView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    this.context = context;
}

@Override
public void setText(CharSequence text, BufferType type) {
    //I get a NullPointerException here since var context is null
    Context applicationContext = context.getApplicationContext();

    if (text != null && applicationContext instanceof MyApplication && applicationContext.doUppercase()) {

        MyApplication myApp = (MyApplication) applicationContext;
        myApp.getLanguagesController().getLocalizedString(text.toString().toUpperCase());
    }
    super.setText(text, type);
}
}
```

In the layout, I have it declared like this

```
            <my.package.UpperTextView
            android:id="@+id/foo"
            android:text="bar"/>
```

I get a NullPointerException when invoking `context.getApplicationContext()`.

Did anyone already came across this?

Comment: you don't need to keep track of the context, you can call getContext from within a View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should try this :

```
this.getContext().getApplicationContext()
```

This should not return you null pointer exception.

Answer (score 0):

Check the link below to know when to use getApplicationContext() and when to use Activity Context

[When to call activity context OR application context?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7298731/when-to-call-activity-context-or-application-context)

Most of the times it is better to use Activity context

Answer (score 0):

It's incorrect way for localization. Check below link:
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/localization.html

Comment: Thing is, transalations are provided by the server... Therefore I cannot use the resources folders for it